# How to fix image with in a limit?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fix an image in **[my site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/SharQ/shop/shrqproduct/)**  product page. The image should be fixed according to the options. I added the following code, but images float above the content also..

```
var images = jQuery('.single-product .images');

jQuery.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
   var $this = this,
     $window = jQuery(window);

 $window.scroll(function (e) {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos - $this.height()
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 'auto'


        });
    }
});
};

 images.followTo(jQuery('#myTab').offset().top - images.height());
```

I also trying with 0, 100 and different values in 'auto' but not working
Please help me to fix this issue... Thanks!

**update**
[image]

Comment: i would like to fix the image and scroll with the options. but it not need to scroll above the content.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#yourDiv').followTo(250);
```

**JSFiddle**
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/essj4nz2/)

> Update 1:

```
images.followTo(($("#myTab").offset().top)-(images.offset().top)- images.outerHeight());
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/8pz8qj8r/)

Comment: (".product_info_left").followTo(250);

Comment: need image scrolls upto the blank space only, no need to overlap the content,it stop when tabs start.

Comment: images.followTo((".product_info_left").height()- images.height());

Comment: try this: `images.followTo((".product_info_left").height()-images.offset().top- images.height());`

Comment: $.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

images.followTo((".product_info_left").height()-images.offset().top- images.height());